# Trouble using fread_s in VS2017

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

Im trying to read an array of numbers from a text file. Im using Visual Studio 2017 - Im having trouble using `fread_s()`. Any way of reading array of numbers from file would be welcome.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "tchar.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    errno_t err_code;
    int i_i;
    int *arr_p;
    int ch[10];
    i_i = 0;
    arr_p = &ch[0];

    if ((err_code = fopen_s(&fp, "test.txt", "r")) != 0)
    {
        printf("File was not opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d :: %d ::%d \n", *arr_p, sizeof(ch), sizeof(int));
        // This line of code, should ideally read the first number in the file
        fread_s(arr_p, sizeof(ch), sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: . o O ( Is there some reason for people to believe that nothing before main is actually part of the code?? )

Comment: How about you \*first\* `fread_s()` and then `printf()`?

Comment: #include "stdio.h"
#include "tchar.h"
#include "stdlib.h"  Sorry, just new to posting on here, so wasnt able to fit this in properly.